# is it possible to install a module from a theme to a different theme in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have 2 themes in prestashop and I would like to install the module from theme1 to theme2? is it possible? i would just want a pointing start..I installed the module but it doesn't appear in the front of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Your module might be hooked to a column or a container not displayed on your theme.

You should check the module code and find where it is hooked and checked that this hook exist in your theme. (for example left and right columns).

Comment: I've installed the module from the admin side and when I go to see the files of the modules they don't appear in the cpanel side